# Firebase Cloud Message appears only if iOS app is in background

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging into a React Native app and have a nifty problem on iOS: If the app is in the background, the notification shows as expected, but if the app is in the foreground then nothing happens.

I have added the AppDelegate.m code from the RNFirebase documentation, including the withCompletionHandler variants which I understand are new for iOS 10:

```
// From https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.3.x/messaging/ios:
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
    [RNFirebaseMessaging willPresentNotification:notification withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    [RNFirebaseMessaging didReceiveNotificationResponse:response withCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Inside the react-native app, I have an onMessage handler which works as advertised in the iOS simulator and on Android:

```
// ...Initializing Firebase...
messaging.onMessage(handleMessage);

// Handle a message:
function handleMessage(message) {
  console.log('Firebase: Received message:', message);

  const theActualMessage = message.fcm ? message.fcm : message.notification;

  if (typeof message.finish === 'function') {
    message.finish();
  }

  Alert.alert('Push message', theActualMessage.body);
}
```

Whether I send the push notification from the Firebase console or via the HTTP API, the notification only appears on iOS (on a real device) if the app is in the background; my `handleMessage()` function is never called.

In the iOS simulator, the Android simulator, and on an Android handset, my handler is called as expected -- only a real iOS device misbehaves.